# how to avoid null pointer exception in java

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

There are two methods

```
 public EmployeeBean viewEmployeeByID(String EmployeeID)

 public EmployeeBean findByID(String id)
```

Given, the description of each method of what it supposed to do

```
public EmployeeBean findByID(String id)
```

- This method should use the JDBC select statements to retrieve the record based on the given Employee ID,
- Store the fields in the EmployeeBean and return the Employee bean.
- In case of any JDBCExceptions or if the id does not exist in the database then a null value needs to be returned

`public EmployeeBean viewEmployeeByID(String EmployeeID)`

- Invoke the findByID(String id) method of the EmployeeDAO class.
- If record is found, the details should be stored in a EmployeeBean object and returned.
- If record is NOT found or has INVALID empID (such as an empty string “”), then the EmployeeBean should be assigned null and returned.

Code is written below for each method

```
public EmployeeBean findById(String id){
 EmployeeBean emp = null;

 try{
     statement = DBUtil.getDBConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL WHERE EMPID=?");
     statement.setString(1,id);

     if(statement.executeUpdate() == 1 ){
         resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
         while(resultSet.next()){
             emp = new EmployeeBean(
                     resultSet.getString(1),
                     resultSet.getString(2),
                     resultSet.getDate(3),
                     resultSet.getString(4),
                     resultSet.getFloat(5)
                     );
         }
         return emp;
     }
     else{
         return null;
     }
 }catch(SQLException e){
     return null;
 }catch(NullPointerException e){
     return null;
 }       
 }




public EmployeeBean viewEmployeeByID(String empId){

      if((employeeBean = this.database.findById(empId)) != null)
      return employeeBean;
          return (EmployeeBean = null);

 }
```

If i try to find an ID which is not present in the database , it returns null  and i get null pointer exception .

Questions

1. Did my snippet statisfy all the requirements given above for each method . if it is not so , please let me know
2. Is there any way to avoid null pointer exception ?

Comment: Does your viewEmployeeByID compile , i don't think so

Comment: *"If record is NOT found or has INVALID empID (such as an empty string “”), then the EmployeeBean should be assigned null and returned."* Seems to satisfy the requirements.  When you get a value back from these methods, you need to test for a `null` return result.  The other solution would be to throw a "Record Not Found" exception, but that might simply be a little excesive

Comment: @JunedAhsan It compiled but whenever i pass the wrong id i get the null error

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why are you using `executeUpdate` to execute a select statement (compliant drivers should always throw an exception if you do that, btw)? You should use `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet does not compile as first since you have 2 return statements.
Also the code satisfied the conditions.
But inside your `findById()` you should check if the `resultSet != null` before doing anything else with that. Then that would avoid NPE in your case.

Comment: "Your snippet does not compile as first since you have 2 return statements." Can you please tell me what i am supposed to do ?

Comment: I would say the same. Avoiding NullPointerException can only be done by doing the not null check. And it can be done on all the objects before making a call to them. Including statement, connection.

Comment: keep `return employeeBean;` and remove the other